# Samsung Keyboard Autocomplete Event

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, dom-events, samsung-mobile

I have an input field like:

```html
<input id="someinput" class="input handle is-rounded" type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="email@example.com" />
```

On this input element, I call a function:

```
function onChangeInput(element, fn) {
  element.addEventListener('blur', fn);
  element.addEventListener('change', fn);
  element.addEventListener('input', fn);
}

onChangeInput(document.getElementById('someinput'), function() {alert('event');});
```

Even without 'blur' or 'change' this seems to fire off for autocomplete events from GBoard on Android, but apparently this is still insufficient for the Samsung keyboard. I don't know if JQuery gracefully handles the Samsung keyboard, but I've come this far without using it.

If anyone could provide vanilla javascript to capture autocomplete/autofill events more generally, or at least from the Samsung keyboard, I'd be grateful.

Comment: set type = email and check again

Comment: If I use type="email", then I can't control the cursor position after a paste event because those calls are ignored if type is anything other than "text."